# How can I scrape content from a Website with AlchemyAPI?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, alchemyapi, alchemy, watson

I would like to scrape Content from a website with AlchemyAPI. I get informed about this feature on http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/scrape/qlang.html

I will implement it in the same way as in the example:"Querying Inside Tables (Selecting a Column Inside a Specific Row)".

Could somebody please help me, how to use this in Node.js and Cquery? Which parameters do I need to get specific fields like price as output?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not currently possible to do this. Since AlchemyAPI was acquired by IBM, the remaining services have been incorporated into Watson. Most of the AlchemyAPI services are now covered in the Natural Language Understanding (NLU) service: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/natural-language-understanding/ but there is no feature that allows you to scrape content from a web site per se.

The NLU service does allow you to retrieve text from a web page using the analyze endpoint: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#post-analyze